# Changing game variables through network in run time for debugging

Tags: server, debugging, console, websocket

I want to implement a system in my game that will allow me to change in game parameters on runtime through the network.
Lets say my game is running on a ps4 or xbox one, I want to be able to register the desired variables in this sub system (for example, lighting values, controls senstivity and other in game parameters) and have them changed in run time from my computer so I don't have to re compile or re-run the game for only small change.
This will be used for debugging and tuning purposes only of course.
I was thinking about something like websockets or have some kind of server in my game that will listen to HTTP requests, maybe use REST APIs and creating an html page for changing the desired parameters.

My knowledge on the subject of web development is very limited so I'm looking for advice here, what do you use for something like that?

I don't even know what to search for so I decided to ask here fist.

Comment: This doesn't really have much to do with web development, however you would be required to build in a miniature http server into your game that responds correctly to requests for this to function correctly.. It may very well be cheaper to just recompile/rerun because this is not a simple task :) Never mind the fact that a constant connection like web sockets may also have an affect on performance

Comment: ok, but this module will be for debug only and I can remove it later on, so performance shouldn't be a problem.